# Joining xls file with shapefile attribute through ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, attribute-joins, iteration

I have folder contains xls files and I need to make join for each file with a shapefile attribute using ModelBuilder.

My trial is as follows:

[image]

and obtained "`Precondition`" option only.

How can I solve it?

Comment: I have found Excel to be quite flaky in model builder I would convert the work sheet to a table as part of your workflow and then join the table.

Comment: Are there tools in modelbuilder to convert sheet to table?

Comment: Yes, search the help file for "excel to table".